# Real-time-ability python multiprocessing (Queue and Pipe)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am a little bit confused testing the multiprocessing module.

Let's simulate a digital timer. The code would look like:

```
start=datetime.now()
while True:
    now=datetime.now()
    delta=now-start
    s = delta.seconds + delta.microseconds/1E6
    print s
    time.sleep(1)
```

Which returns correctly:

```
8e-06
1.001072
2.00221
3.003353
4.004416
...
```

Now I want to read the clock from my virtual external digital clock device using a pipe:

```
def ask_timer(conn):

    start=datetime.now()
    while True:
        now=datetime.now()
        delta=now-start
        s = delta.seconds + delta.microseconds/1E6
        conn.send(s)


parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
p = Process(target=ask_timer, args=(child_conn,))
p.start()


while True:
    print parent_conn.recv()
    time.sleep(1)
```

It returns:

```
2.9e-05
6.7e-05
7.7e-05
8.3e-05
8.9e-05
9.4e-05
0.0001
...
```

Here the  timer doesn't seem to run permanently in the background..The implementation of "Queue" looks like:

```
def ask_timer(q):    

    while True:
        now=datetime.now()
        delta=now-start
        s = delta.seconds + delta.microseconds/1E6
        q.put(s)
        #conn.close()




q = Queue()
p = Process(target=ask_timer, args=(q,))
p.start()


while True:
    print q.get()
    time.sleep(1)
```

which does the same like pipe. Is this just my misconception of multiprocessing of python? How could I ask a value realtime from a running parallel-thread?

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working correctly. The child process is executing `ask_timer()` function completely independently from you main process. You don't have any `time.sleep()` in this function, so it just prints or puts in the queue deltas in the infinite loop with interval of like 10ms.

Once a second your main process asks child process for data and get's it. Data is one of those small intervals.

The problem there is that you're putting much more data into pipe/queue, than taking from it. So you're getting old data, when you ask. To test that you can print queue size in the loop (won't work on OS X):

```
def ask_timer(q):
    start = datetime.now()
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        delta = now - start
        s = delta.seconds + delta.microseconds / 1E6
        q.put(s)


q = Queue()
p = Process(target=ask_timer, args=(q,))
p.start()

while True:
    print q.get()
    print q.qsize()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The queue size will grow really fast.

---

Apparently you can use [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to read current value from the child process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value
from datetime import datetime
import time
from ctypes import c_double


def ask_timer(v):
    start = datetime.now()
    while True:
        now = datetime.now()
        delta = now - start
        s = delta.seconds + delta.microseconds / 1E6
        v.value = s


val = Value(c_double, 0.0)
p = Process(target=ask_timer, args=(val,))
p.start()

while True:
    print(val.value)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Well I also suspected this. But how to only pass the actual value, I mean like not append to an array, but overwrite the value s?

Comment: @Caniko see added part.

Comment: are you sure that transfering over a file or http will really fit my demands? Reading at 15kHz and transfer 1-5kHz ?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Because I don't know your demands. I stated that there is no easy solution for retrieving current value from another process using Python. Also I suggested possible solution for this problem. That's it. "Reading at 15kHz and transfer 1-5kHz ?" - I have no idea what does it mean. But if performance is so critical that you need direct interaction between processes, maybe C is a better choice, than Python?

Comment: Well that means that I need a better performance than processing serial. Today I posted another question about the same thing you mentioned :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010631/the-most-efficient-way-to-parallelize-a-python-and-a-c-code

Comment: @Caniko Apparently I was not right. Reviewed `multiprocessing` documentation just in case and found that you can achieve reading current state using shared memory. See updated answer.